# XCode: to create IPA Archive, is it always in release mode?

Tags: xcode, ipa

When i create an IPA for AdHoc-Distribution via XCode -> Product -> Archive, will the code be always compiled in release mode or depends it on the current scheme which is selected for debugging the app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will depend on the build configuration you have set in scheme edit panel

You can access it via `Product` -> `Scheme` -> Edit Scheme`or`⌘<`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Which version is compiled depends on what is selected in the scheme.

You need to set the scheme to do Release build for the Archive action.